# Scope of variable (Is it not set)? [Java]

Tags: java, cookies

So I'm trying to store the cookies of one connection, and then re-use them in the future. However, it seems as when I set the cookies and then call the next function, they seem to disappear.

Main.java

```
Bumper thread = Threads.get(x); //looping through a list
thread.login();
thread.bump();
```

Bumper.java

```
public class Bumper {
    CookieStore cookies;

    public void setCookies(CookieStore cookie){
        this.cookies = cookie;
    }

    public CookieStore getCookyz(){
        return this.cookies;
    }

    public void login() throws Exception {

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);
    httpClient.start();

    Fields fieldForm = new Fields();

    fieldForm.add("do","login");
    fieldForm.add("url","");
    fieldForm.add("vb_login_md5password", this.password);
    fieldForm.add("vb_login_md5password_utf", this.password);
    fieldForm.add("s", "");
    fieldForm.add("vb_login_username", this.username);
    fieldForm.add("vb_login_password", "");

    FormContentProvider form = new FormContentProvider(fieldForm);


    ContentResponse response = httpClient.POST("http://www.sythe.org/login.php?do=login")
            .agent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .content(form)
            .send();

          this.setCookies(httpClient.getCookieStore());
            for(HttpCookie c : this.getCookyz().getCookies())
                System.out.println(c.toString());
          System.out.println("Logged In");
    }

    public void bump() throws Exception {           
            for(HttpCookie c : this.getCookyz().getCookies())
                System.out.println(c.toString());
            System.out.println("Bumped"); 
    }
}
```

What is output

```
  __cfduid=d059a09bfabef0a5bae2e318891450085011
    bblastvisit=14505011
    bblastactivity=0
    bbsessionhash=7b6c57cd6a62a20e144cd
    Logged In (The termination of the Login function)
    Bumped (The termination of the Bump function)
```

Where on earth did the cookies go from one function to the other? Why are they not preserved? It prints the cookies in one function(login), but then seem to be non-existent in the next (bump).

I have tried putting different identifiers on the "cookies" variable to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Some of the relevant context may be hidden in the `...` of login(). Try posting a complete but cut-down version (less code) of your program that still has the problem.

Comment: It's probably because you're getting cookies from your cookie store in both methods via `this.getCookies().getCookies()`, which you have installed in login() via `this.setCookies(...)` but not populated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately that doesnt seem to be it. Its extremely confusing, I updated the code. this.getCookies() calls the method to return the CookieStore, and then .getCookies() gets the cookies as a list so I can iterate through them. That being said its super confusing and I have fixed the naming. (although it isnt perfect)

Comment: The naming of `getCookyz()` doesn't matter here. Which piece of code stores things in the cookie store? I.e. when do you put stuff into `this.cookies` via (e.g.) `this.cookies.putCookie(...)`?